# Soapui - Rest request keeps spinning even after getting a response

Tags: rest, soapui

I am updating the parameters through groovy and executing a get request approx 5k times

Approx 1k request runs fine after which request keeps spinning. When i see the request response window, i see response is already present. It keeps spinning for a while and then next approx 600 requests executes and so on...

I am unsure why the request keeps spinning even after receiving a response. This is increasing the execution time subsequently.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the service is responding? Check the logs.

Comment: Yes. It works when I execute a single request.